# Nested UIScrollViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a mainScrollView scrolling horizontally with photos added to it and mainScrollView's contentSize is set according to the number of photos.

To achieve the effect of scrolling to the end and swiping in a UIView with display info for user, I added the overlayScrollView to mainScrollView's subviews.

overlayScrollView contains the contentView positioned outside the frame.

```
CGRect frame = self.mainScrollView.frame;
frame.origin.x = CGRectGetWidth(frame) * (count-1); 

UIScrollView *overlayScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[self.mainScrollView addSubview:overlayScrollView];

// moves contentView one frame beyond
frame.origin.x = CGRectGetWidth(frame);
UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[overlayScrollView addSubview:contentView];

overlayScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(overlayScrollView.frame.size.width * 2, overlayScrollView.frame.size.height);
overlayScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
```

I searched through SO on nested UIScrollViews and so subclassed UIScrollView for mainScrollView with the following method:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    for (UIView *child in self.subviews){
    if([child isMemberOfClass:[UIScrollView class]])
        if(CGRectContainsPoint(child.frame, point))
            return child;
    }
    return self;
}
```

But it doesn't work. My code could be wrong. hitTest did return child (overlayScrollView) but did not scroll. Any suggestions how to code this?

Comment: Does the user ever actually pan the scroll view? Could you achieve the effect you want with one scroll view and an animation on the frame of another view?

Comment: Yes it works with only one photo - both scrollviews are within the same frame, mainScrollView is not scrolling and contentView slides in.